# I am trying to decode a compressed rtp packet to evs and make it into a wav file

Tags: c, ipv6, rtp, codec

I am trying to decode a compressed rtp packet to evs and make it into a wav file.

I use C language in Redhat 6.8 64bit environment.

I have rtp packet dump ( evs )

I used EVS_dec in 3GPP TS 26.443 V15.1.0. C source code.

rtp packet -> g.192 format file -> wav

I have successfully created a wav file, but I can not hear it.

3gpp It does not understand well when I look at the document.

I want to know more about how to use EVS_dec.

Comment: Please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [make a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You need to provide enough information whan you already tried. You shouldn't ask people to do all the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Media Pipeline should be

RTP Unpack (buffer with EVS encoded data) -> EVS decoder (buffer with PCM Data)-> Wav File Writer ( Pcm data is written in a wav file)

STEPS to be followed:

you need to write a RTP stack to handle the unpacking .
Use the EVS codec to decode the EVS payload data.
Write the PCM data to a wave file.

Comment: I get raw data from pcap file. but I can't get EVS codec data from this raw data.
how can I get EVS codec from pcap file?

Comment: Please check the rfc6884, 12 bytes of RTP header + EVS header ( similar to AMR header )